# How to add latest dependency ZXing android embedded (2017)

Tags: java, android, dependencies, zxing

I've started a new project in Android Studio and I want to import the zxing-android-embedded to allow me to create a simple barcode scanner within my application.

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.barcodescanner"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0'
}
```

It Shows Error that

```
Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
<a href="disable.gradle.offline.mode">Disable offline mode and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/user/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidStudioProjects/BarCodeScanner/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

and

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0
<a href="disable.gradle.offline.mode">Disable offline mode and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/user/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidStudioProjects/BarCodeScanner/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Well, I searched Stack Overflow but was unable to find the latest Dependency ZXing android embedded.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'   
}
```